# session post with verify not working in python3.7.2

Tags: python, session, post

Below code in python2.7 not giving any error but with some ssl warnings . On python 3.7.2 with requests version 2.22.0 the below code response is "500 Internal Server Error"

```
import requests  
sslverification = True  
payload = {}  
payload["username"] = userName  
payload["password"] = password 
payload["targeturl"] = targeturl  
print("Authenticating....")  
response = session.post(idpurl, data=payload , verify=sslverification)  
print (response.text)
```

for 3.7 , displaying below error

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>500 Internal Server Error</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Internal Server Error</h1>
<p>The server encountered an internal error or
misconfiguration and was unable to complete
your request.</p>
<p>Please contact the server administrator,
 you@example.com and inform them of the time the error occurred,
and anything you might have done that may have
caused the error.</p>
<p>More information about this error may be available
in the server error log.</p>
</body></html>
```

Any suggestions on this issue?
Required any changes in session post method arguments while calling?

Comment: where are you sending this request to?

Comment: There is a target url which is outside official network and a third party applicaiton , hence the idpurl will check/provide the user credentials then will be posted to target url.

Comment: yes, but where exactly are you sending this request to? iirc sites such as amazon prevents access of their api through external applications

Comment: yes, the target url is AWS only , but how come the error not seen in python2.7. the script is to generate aws_secret_access_key using boto2 AWS SDK and was successful in python2.7. Now just trying to update with python3.7 and boto3 versions.

Comment: 'payload["targeturl"] = targeturl ' is the culprit , instead of  targeturl, changed to target as 'payload["target"] = targeturl'. now "500 Internal Server Error" is no more , but still there is difference in results between python2.7 , python3.7